# VS 2010 stops responding when opening form designer

Tags: vb.net

I have VisualBasic project wih many forms,and one of it is form1.Whenever the initializecimponent method is called,VS stops responding and i have to end it using taskmgr.The bug is inside the form1.designer.vb, because i am able to view and edit other forms and usercontrols in designer.Anoter strange thing is that the stand alone exe runs successfully outside the IDE.I also tried adding the form to another project and that project too crashes.Whenever i build/debug/view form1 in designer, i get two dialogs one after the other:VS2010 has stopped working, VS2010 is restarting( but it never does!)

Comment: I would recommend opening the designer document in notepad - "formname.designer.vb" and posting that as well. Also, if you know of any DLLs you are referencing, and if you are using any resources - you might want to mention that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a copy of the form, and begin removing parts of the form until it works.  The last thing you removed is what failed.  You'll have to do this manually by removing three parts of each control:

- The Declaration (at the bottom)
- The instantiation (at the top)
- The configuration (in the middle). Below is an example of the configuration

---

```
  '
  'LeftLabel
  '
  Me.LeftLabel.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
  Me.LeftLabel.AutoSize = True
  Me.LeftLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
  Me.LeftLabel.Name = "LeftLabel"
  Me.LeftLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
  Me.LeftLabel.TabIndex = 1
  Me.LeftLabel.Text = "Label2"
```

You'll also need to remove any references to that control, such as it being added to a container.

Do this one control at a time, then build the project and open the form.  If the form does NOT open, restart visual studio and do the next control.  if it DOES open, then the last thing you removed was the culprit.

Comment: The form is very heavy and has hundreds of controls( its like a mini os).It is humanly impossible to do trial and error for each control.Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Disagree.  Think of a binary search. Take the first half of controls, and remove them. Still break? you know it's in the other half. Lather, rinse, repeat. O(logn) right there.  I don't see any other way to handle this, given that these 'hundreds of controls' are unknown to use, there's no error message to provide, etc.  The only thing we know is 'theres controls. vs errors'...

Comment: One could also easily argue that a form with 'hundreds of controls' is destined to become more and more unwieldy and unstable.  Consider breaking that down into other forms or user controls. makes things much, much more manageable.

Comment: Thanx I will give it a try.Actually my project is complete and now I am breaking the program to smaller modules as you said.

Comment: I fixed the problem. This is what I did: created a dummy form called form 2.Opened form1.designer.VB in text editor.copied all the  declarations in Form1.designer to form 2.designer.then copied initializecomponent method of form1 to form 2 until the form 2 crashes.The culprit was a user control  metro_tile. Everything became fine .when I deleted its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For programmers facing the same problem, here is the solution:
Make sure that your user controls doesn't creates instances of themselves inside themselves.even though your program might run without any error, VS designer will crash.here is an example for such kind of code:

```
Public class controlx
   public sub new()
      dim x as new controlx
   End sub
End class
```

you might think its a silly logical error, but such errors can be very much frustrating and time consuming.always breakdown your code to smaller units so that its manageable as Brian said.